# Summing cells from another sheet using offset

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get this code to work for summing cells:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Offset(i, j).Formula = "=Sum("
&Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Offset(2*i,j).Address & ":" &
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").Offset(2*i,j).Address & ")"
```

It keeps giving me the right cells but from the wrong sheet. So for the first iteration I get sum(A3:A7) in cell C3 of Sheet2 but the A3:A7 stays referenced to Sheet2 not Sheet1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the name of the sheet in the formula too. Your code will work if you write it like this:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Offset(i, j).Formula = "=Sum(Sheet1!" & _
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Offset(2 * i, j).Address & ":" & _
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A7").Offset(2 * i, j).Address & ")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code - it uses the `External:=True` parameter of `.Address`to retrieve the full address. While this also includes the workbook name, Excel will remove this automatically so you end up with Sheet1!A3. Also note that I used the range `A3:A7` as source as `.Address` can handle multi-cell ranges and you don't need to take care of it manually:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Offset(i, j).Formula = "=SUM(" & _
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A7").Offset(2 * i, j).Address(External:=True) & ")"
```

Be aware that hard coding references such as `A3` can lead to bugs in the long run, as the user (or even the developer at some stage) might modify the sheet structure. It is best practice to use named ranges, i.e. create a named range for each cell/range you refer to and then access it in VBA with `SheetX.Range("rngStartCell")` or similar!